# How to write log files so they can be viewed with tail -f on windows

Tags: windows, logging

We have a large Windows C++ application with a ton of logging code. Via macros and several logging related classes it boils down to CRT file operations like fopen and fprintf. One problem with this approach is we cannot view logs as they are written with "tail -f" or LogExpert. They complain that the file is in use.

What's the easiest way to change things to the log files can be read as they are written? Would switching from fopen/fprintf to CreateFile/WriteFile with FILE_SHARE_READ work? But is there a way to make it work and stick with fopen/fprintf. Or in general what is the best approach here? And can someone confirm they can view log files as they are written with their Windows application?

Comment: I made a a small console program that writes to a file with fopen/fprint, there I can open the file while it's still being written to. So it's not an inherent problem with fopen/printf, it must be something different our main program does which locks the file?

Comment: Would [_fsopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db(v=vs.80).aspx) work? Sounds promising.